# Print japanese characters with node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a telegram bot that takes a string (japanese or spanish) and translate it using Google Translate's **scraper** (this one https://github.com/statickidz/node-google-translate-free).

I tested it on Mac and works fine. But when I'm trying to deploy it on my VPS (Debian 8.3), it doesn't return japanese characters.

All I get, in Telegram and terminal, is this:

> �����ɂ���'

Must be a charcode failure, but it seems UTF-8 in both sides...

**UPDATE**

My code for output is this:

```
sakura.onText(/\/esp (.+)/, function (msg, match) {
  var fromId = msg.from.id;
  var input  = match[1];
  translate({ text: input, source: 'es', target: 'ja' }, function(result) { sakura.sendMessage(fromId, "'" + input + "', traducido, significa '" + result + "'."); });
});
```

I've tested with japanese `locales` for Debian. Linux output are in japanese, but not my bot's output.

Comment: Most likely a terminal settings problem.

Comment: I'm using Terminator and it support katakana.

Comment: Katakana is just one set of characters. It could be that Terminator cannot find the font for Japanese, or the font is set to one that does not support it. Or it could be that the locale needs to be set to UTF-8 if it is not already. (One suggestion is `LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8" in /etc/rc.conf` and `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`. Just guessing.

Comment: Server has locale set to japanese UTF-8. I think it could be Node... Is there any way to force output to UTF-8?

Comment: Possibly, show the line/API you are using for output.

Comment: Sorry for the late! OP updated.

Comment: you can use var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved using [`iconv`](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite) for UTF-8 encode.

Comment: Which code should I use to encode japan characters?